# Bash behaviour customisation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using GNU Bash 4.2.5 with fedora 18.

Whenever I'm typing something into the shell say

```
pe<tab>
```

I get an annoying error sound, I then have to press tab again to view the auto-complete suggestions, I was wondering if it's possible to make it so that instead of throwing me an error the first time and making a bell/ping sound, it directly prints auto complete suggestions the first time I hit tab.

I still want to have the "Display all 172 possibilities?[y/N]" like warnings available.

I don't know how I can customize bash behaviour so, since I've never attempted something like this before, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

Basic customization of bash's completion behavior can be performed by modifying various readline variables in `~/.inputrc`. See the `bash(1)` man page, **READLINE** section, **Readline Variables** subsection, for details.